# How to implement CREATE in controller in ASP.NET Core Web App (with repository design pattern)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I currently have the following code in my Orders controller but once I run the program and attempt to create an order, it stays on the create screen.

Note that I require a drop down list with customer's Id, hence the create method also makes use of the `customerRepository`.

```
    // GET: Orders/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(_customerRepository.GetAll(), "CustomerId", "CustomerId");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Orders/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create([Bind("OrderId,OrderDate,CustomerId,DeliveryAddress")] Order order)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            order.CustomerId = int.Parse(Request.Form["CustomerId"]);
            _orderRepository.Create(order);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        // If ModelState is invalid, repopulate the ViewBag with the list of customers
        ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(_customerRepository.GetAll(), "CustomerId", "CustomerId");
        return View(order);
    }
```

I suspect that my model state is invalid as it stays on the create view once I submit an entry, I don't know how to fix it in order to successfully create an order.

Comment: Why don't you check ModelState errors?

Comment: Hi Adel, please follow  YasinARLI's suggestion to check the [modelstate error details.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bfSCZf)